# Could not add the specified data object to the map

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, postgresql, layers, import

I have registered the postgresql database with arcgis desktop 10.1.

In ArcMap, When I try to drag and drop one of the tables to the map I get this error:

```
Could not add the specified data object to the map
```

I want to Add data as a layer to the map using the data tables in postgresql database rather than using add layer plugin and import .csv file form another location.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? Does it meet ArcGIS 10.1 System Requirements i.e.
PostgreSQL 9.0.5 (64-bit) or 9.1.3 (64-bit).

Comment: psotgresql 9.2. and yes the problem is it is not supported by arcgis 10.1 . Thanks PolyGeo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be encountering bug [NIM087647](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDg3NjQ3) which suggests:

> Alternate Solution
>
> Use the Add Data button in ArcMap to add the table to the table of
>   contents.

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by adding a unique identifier field to layer before attempting to import it. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 and ArcDesktop 10.3 which should be a miss-match. Some of my layers imported fine,others threw the error you posted. I noticed the difference between importing or not was the presence of a "unique identifier" field. Double click the layer in the db tree to edit it and add the field.